# Cron to Bash Script to Bash Script to Expect Script

Tags: bash, cron, expect

I want to execute a series of Expect scripts. The chain of execution goes like this:
Cron job starts a bash script, this wrapper starts ~11 bash scripts in `Parallel` - each of them call an `Expect` script.

All is well until the `Expect` portion. I have the Parallel portion in the 2nd Bash script spitting out the hostnames for each expect script into a file. The do in fact appear in groups, but the Expect script dies immediately.

I have heard that due to the nature of Cron jobs I need to pass environment variables to the job. I've tried this so far:

```
48 9 * * * rm /home/admin/.flag && /home/admin/.profile; /home/admin/nodeTest.sh
```

nodeTest's significant code is:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
                for chunk in `ls /home/admin/assets/sagLogs/x*`; do
                        cat $chunk | parallel -j 11 -I% --max-args 1 /home/abdmin/oneNode.sh "%"
                        clear
                done
        done
```

The chunks are 11 hostnames long. They get put into the parallel program to start the Expect script via oneNode - oneNode just translates the hostname to IP and determines which script to run.

This works just fine from the commandline; just the Cron job that's giving me grief. I've read that the `interact` tcl command causes issues, but I don't use it in my scripts. This is the line that is run in parallel:

```
timeout 80 sudo expect /home/admin/assets/activeTest $sag $ip &
```

Update:
changed the previous line to:

```
timeout 80 sudo /usr/bin/expect /home/admin/assets/activeTest $sag $ip &
```

**Update: After inspecting errors from the Expect script, what I'm running into is a lack of imported env variables. The first error occurs because the `TERM` variable is == unknown:**

```
'unknown': I need something more specific.
    while executing
"exec /usr/bin/clear"
    invoked from within
"puts [exec /usr/bin/clear]"
    (file "/home/admin/assets/activeTest" line 35)
```

When I dump env from the calling script (oneNode) I can see term is set:

```
TEMR=vt100
```

So it's set in the wrapper, but it doesn't get inherited by the expect script. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong

```
48 9 * * * rm /home/admin/.flag && /home/admin/.profile; /home/admin/nodeTest.sh
```

Most crucially, you *execute .profile as a command* -- that executes it in a *separate process* and when that process exits, all environment modification disappear with it.

Also, what happens if `.flag` doesn't exist? You won't process the profile, but you still run the nodeTest script.

I suggest you want to `source` the .profile. Use `rm -f` so no errors occur if the file is missing. And only execute the script if there are no errors in the .profile.

```
48 9 * * * rm -f /home/admin/.flag; . /home/admin/.profile && /home/admin/nodeTest.sh
# ..................................^
# source the .profile: execute it in the _current_ shell
```

Next, [don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Change

```
            for chunk in `ls /home/admin/assets/sagLogs/x*`; do
                    cat $chunk | ...
```

to

```
            for chunk in /home/admin/assets/sagLogs/x*; do
                    cat "$chunk" | ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a go.

Comment: Hi Glenn - this didn't seem to work entirely. My expect scripts die very quickly because of lines like `puts [exec clear]` and lines that point to one of my scripts that uses the `tput` program. Any ideas?